# Match number in each row of R data frame from another df and add a letter ahead of the matched number

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two dataframes. I'd like to match items in df1 with those in df2 and if there's a match, then a letter would be appended in front of the matched number in data frame's row. I have written some bit of code, but I'm not sure how to get ahead. Any pointers would be helpful. Thanks.

Here's an example df1:

```
S.no       number   
1           122, apple, 22, banana 
2           145, 20, 45
3           212, grapes, 33  
4           250, sugar, 43

items to be matched from this dataframe df2:

S.no       number   
1           122
2           186
3           212
4           250
5           111
6           45
```

Output DF

```
S.no       number   
1           S122, apple, 22, banana 
2           145, 20, S45
3           S212, grapes, 33  
4           S250, sugar, 43
```

Here's what I have done so far:

```
df1 <- df1 %>% 
  mutate(ID = row_number()) %>% 
  separate_rows(`number`, sep = ',') %>% 
  left_join(df2, by = "S.no") %>%  
  group_by(ID) %>%
```

Not sure how to go ahead after this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr` and `tidyr` we can first `separate_rows` of `df1` and `left_join` it with `df2`, `paste` `"S"` to `number` which have a match and then `summarise them again.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>%
  separate_rows(number) %>%
  left_join(df2 %>% mutate(number = as.character(number)), by = "number") %>%
  mutate(number = ifelse(is.na(Sno.y), number, paste0("S", number))) %>%
  select(-Sno.y) %>%
  group_by(Sno.x)  %>%
  summarise(number = toString(number))

#  Sno.x number                 
#  <int> <chr>                  
#1     1 S122, apple, 22, banana
#2     2 145, 20, S45           
#3     3 S212, grapes, 33       
#4     4 S250, sugar, 43
```

**data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(Sno = 1:4, number = c("122, apple, 22, banana", 
"145, 20, 45", "212, grapes, 33", "250, sugar, 43")), class = 
"data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

df2 <- structure(list(Sno = 1:6, number = c(122L, 186L, 212L, 250L, 
111L, 45L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 2):

As a one liner using base `R`

```
df1$number = gsub(paste0("(.*)(",paste(df2$number,collapse="|"),".*)"),"\\1S\\2",df1$number)

  Sno                  number
1   1 S122, apple, 22, banana
2   2            145, 20, S45
3   3        S212, grapes, 33
4   4         S250, sugar, 43
```

Truth be told, this does not work for multiple occurrences inside a single row.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one approach

```
library(tidyverse)

df2 = df2 %>% mutate(number = as.character(number))

df3 = df1 %>% 
  mutate(ID = row_number(),
         number=str_split(number, ",", n=Inf)) %>% 
  unnest() %>% 
  left_join(df2,by=c("number")) %>% 
  mutate(number = ifelse(!is.na(S.no.y), 
                         paste("S", number, sep=""), number)) %>% 
  group_by(S.no.x) %>% 
  mutate(number = paste(number, collapse=",")) %>% 
  distinct(S.no.x, .keep_all=T) %>% 
  select(S.No =S.no.x, number)
```